# Equivalent of " ps aux | grep script.sh | grep -v grep" for windows?

Tags: windows, shell

I am looking for an equivalent/alternative of Linux's "  ps aux | grep  | grep -v grep" in windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in CMD:

```
tasklist | find "task"
```

Test:

```
tasklist | find "cmd.exe"
cmd.exe                      12000 Console                    1      3,348 K
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I tried this already and keep getting this error :FIND parameter format not correct

Comment: @VasanthRaghavan I know you probably fixed it, but you must be skipping the "" around your task name if you get that error.